# How to convert guild.permissions number into an array of persmissions discord.js oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, permissions, discord, passport.js

I need to verify if a user logging into the website has sufficient permissions to modify my bot's behavior on a guild. I used passport-discord to get information on the user, and this is what I got:

```
{
  ...
  guilds: [
    {
      id: 'guild id',
      name: 'guild name',
      icon: 'guild icon',
      owner: false,
      permissions: 104189504,
      features: [Array],
      permissions_new: '1037338791488'
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

For confidentiality purposes, I replaced the guild information above "owner". Now my question: How to convert the "permissions" section into an array of the user's permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an API where you can do it (probably not), but it's not that complicated to implement this. Discord provides two community-created calculators for permissions, which do the opposite thing - you select which permissions you need and you get a calculated permissions result:

- https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#104189504
- https://finitereality.github.io/permissions-calculator/?v=104189504

You could quite easily create a function that will do the reverse - convert the decimal permissions number into a hex number, then map the hexes to named permissions.

E.g. your permission from example `104189504` is `635CE40` in hex representation. Permissions are mapped to 1, 2, 4, or 8, so if you encounter any other hex, it means there is a sum. Thus, your permission int contains the following permissions:

- 4000000
- 2000000
- 200000
- 100000
- 40000
- 10000
- 8000
- 4000
- 800
- 400
- 200
- 40

Which you can then map to names, e.g. 4000000 is "Change nickname", and so on.

Comment: Michal can you try to explain more how you determined those values from the hex. I am trying to do the same thing and I just can not wrap my head around it. I need to check if `8` exists within the BigInt that comes back from the API, but knowing this is all needing to be converted to hex I am unsure how to approach this.

Comment: If you only need to check for the value `8`, then you have to convert the Int to Hex, then check the value of the last digit. If it's >= 8 then `8` is used in the permissions.

Comment: Thanks. I did get this working before your reply I ended up using `(hex_value & 0x08) == 0x08`

Comment: That also does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your bot's permission checks simple, you might find it sufficient to check if the member executing the command has a specific role.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).